# Elasticsearch sort by filtered value

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 7.12, upgrading to 7.17 soon.

The following description of my problem has had the confusing business logic for my exact scenario removed.

I have an integer field in my document named 'Points'. It will usually contain 5-10 values, but may contain more, probably not more than 100 values. Something like:

```
Document 1:
{
  "Points": [3, 12, 34, 60, 1203, 70, 88]
}

Document 2:
{
  "Points": [16, 820, 31, 60]
}

Document 3:
{
  "Points": [93, 20, 55]
}
```

My search needs to return documents with values within a range, such as between 10 and 19 inclusive. That part is fine. However I need to sort the results by the values found in that range. From the example above, I might need to find values between 30-39, sorted by the value in that range ascending - it should return Document 2 (containing value of 31) followed by Document 1 (containing value of 34).

Due to the potential range of values and searches I can't break this field down into fields like 0-9, 10-19 etc. to search on them independently - there would be many thousands of fields.

The documents themselves are otherwise quite large and there are a large number of them, so I have been advised to avoid nested fields if possible.

Can I apply a filter to a sort? Do I need a script to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this:

1. Histogram aggregation

Aggregate your documents using a histogram aggregation with "hard bounds". Example query

```
POST /my_index/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": { "filter": { "range": { "Points": { "gte": "30", "lte" : "40" } } } }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "points": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "Points",
        "interval": 10,
        "hard_bounds": {
          "min": 30,
          "max": 40
        }
      },
      "aggs" : {"top" : {"top_hits" : {}}}
    }
  }
}
```

THis will aggregate all the documents as long as they fall in that range, and the first bucket in the results, will contain the document that you want.

2. Try this with an extended terms aggregation:

If the range you want is relatively small. For eg like you mentioned "30 - 39", a simple terms aggregation on the results with an inclusion for all the numbers in that range, will also give you the desired result.

Example Query:

```
POST /my_index/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": { "filter": { "range": { "Points": { "gte": "30", "lte" : "40" } } } }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "points": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Points",
        "include" : ["30","31"....,"39"]
      },
      "aggs" : {"top": {"top_hits" : {}}}
    }
  }
}
```

Each bucket in the terms aggregation results will contain the documents that have that particular "Point" occurring at least once. The first document in the first bucket has what you want.

3. The third option involves building a runtime field, that will trim the points to contain only the points between your range, and then sorting in ascending order on that field. But that will be slower.

HTH.